# GoogleAuthIOException when trying to get files list in appDataFolder

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to save app database to the Apps folder on Google Drive. I'm using Drive v3 API. 
A few months ago all working fine and data successfully saving to user appData folder. But for now, I'm getting GoogleAuthIOException.
My app has all necessary API keys in Google Console (oAuth, Drive API)

Here is my code:

First, show a dialog to a user, to get his account:

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
        getApplicationContext(), Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA))
        .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
//...
startActivityForResult(
                    mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                    REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
//...
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
 }
}
```

Next, I execute AsyncTask, check current files in the folder (delete it, if needed) and save current database in it.

Full listing of my AsyncTask class:

```
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean> {
    private com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mService;
    File databasePath;
    FileList fileList;

    MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .build();
        databasePath = BackupActivity.this.getDatabasePath(databaseName);
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
        if (params[0]) {
            com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
            fileMetadata.setName(databaseOnGDName);
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/x-sqlite3", databasePath);
            try {
                fileList = mService.files().list().setSpaces("appDataFolder").execute(); //Here error appears
                if (fileList.getFiles().size() == 0) {
                    mService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).execute();
                } else {
                    for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file : fileList.getFiles()) {
                        mService.files().delete(file.getId()).execute();
                    }
                    mService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).execute();
                }
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                fileList = mService.files().list().setSpaces("appDataFolder").execute();
                for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file : fileList.getFiles()) {
                    if (file.getName().equals(databaseOnGDName)) {
                        File appDB = databasePath;
                        InputStream inputStream = mService.files().get(file.getId()).executeMediaAsInputStream();
                        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(appDB);
                        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
                        inputStream.close();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error from logcat:

```
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:299)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at evansir.tarotdivinations.BackupActivity$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(BackupActivity.java:291)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at evansir.tarotdivinations.BackupActivity$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(BackupActivity.java:266)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err: Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zza(Unknown Source:133)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.zza(Unknown Source:21)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.zza(Unknown Source:74)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source:3)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source:5)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source:7)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source:0)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:267)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:292)
2018-10-22 12:34:45.426 8931-9036/evansir.tarotdivinations W/System.err:    ... 12 more
```

How I can see from error - problem in authentification. But all my code is from Google examples for [Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_with_the_google_apis_java_client). How I can resolve this error?

Theoretically, I need to perform some authorization procedure, but I do not find one for my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally found a solution.

First, when a user chooses his account here:

```
startActivityForResult(
                mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
```

I set chosen account using `setSelectedAccount(account, "package")`, instead of `setSelectedAccountName(accountName)`

And I added one more catch to my AsyncTask, it creates a dialog with ask for permission (like noted in [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_with_the_google_apis_java_client)):

```
        try {

            fileList = mService.files().list().setSpaces("appDataFolder").execute();
            //...
            return null;
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorCode = 1;
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_SIGNIN_REQUIRED);
            return true;
}
```